# EF Core method commenting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, comments

I found my self with an application with the following comments:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Update Items
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="items"></param>
        /// <returns>Number records updated</returns>
```

Every Method() has something similar comment. Is this a normal pattern for EF Core C# comments?

Comment: That's standard c# xml documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/

Comment: It's known as XMLDOC. [Here's the C# specs for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/documentation-comments).

Comment: Yes it's normal, and unless you are writing something like a public API where you will be maintaining the comments to the level of a reliable documentation source for your API I would avoid adding comments if they are simply there to point out the bleeding obvious. Your code should be for the most part written in a way that it is dead simple to understand through naming convention and keeping it simple and compact. The problem with comments is that "comments lie", in that code evolves and developers seldom go back to update the comments. I can highly recommend "Clean Code" by Uncle Bob.

Comment: what I am finding is that the Methods are poorly named and they are relying on the comment to explain the logic. thanks!